# Review Cannot be converted to Restaurant

Tags: java, repository, dao

I have included my code above. I have a buffered reader, which I am attempting to use to read textfiles. 
I need Review + Restaurant otherwise I get review values printed as "null"

```
@Override
public Repository load(String filename) {
        Repository repository = new Repository();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            //ArrayList <Review> review=new ArrayList<>();
            String[] revs;
             String line = br.readLine();
               while(line!=null){
                revs=line.split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));       
                int id = Integer.valueOf(revs[0]);
                String name= stripQuotes(revs[1]);
                String location = stripQuotes(revs[2]);          
                Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant(id, name,location);        
                int noreview=Integer.parseInt(revs[3]);    
                for (int i=0; i<noreview; i++) {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    revs=line.split(Character.toString(DELIMITER));    
                    String reviewer = stripQuotes(revs[4]);
                    int rating= Integer.parseInt(revs[5]);
                    Review review = new Review (reviewer, rating);
                    repository.add(restaurant); 
                    repository.add(review);   
                 }

            }   
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAOTextImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return repository;
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing; can you post the full exception and stacktrace please?

Comment: Improve formatting